# Execute Promise tree consecutively from parent to child

Tags: javascript, promise, functional-programming, tree

I want to create a tree structure using nested `Promise`'s.

When the promises resolve in the tree structure it will resolve from the inside out (child then parent). I need to have the execution from parent to child sibling promises can run in parallel.

I have come up with a way to delay the execution by resolving a closure that will delay the action from a resolved promise and recursively calling each function from the top down. It's a fairly elegant solution, however, is there any other convention or Functional object I can use to perform the action. I really don't want to have to resolve a closure from each node in the tree as it will increase the complexity to teach people to use it.

I would prefer to not use async/await and just stick with `Promise`'s or another Functional JS object.

This first example will show the resolved order of the nested Promises.

```js
let order = 0
const promiseTree = (name, children) => 
  Promise.all([
    new Promise(res => res(`${name} order:${order++}`)),
    children && Promise.all(children)
  ])

promiseTree('root', [
  promiseTree('child', [
    promiseTree('grandchild', [
      promiseTree('great grandchild sibling 1'),
      promiseTree('great grandchild sibling 2'),
    ])
  ])
])
.then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js?concise=true"></script>
```

If you resolve a closure, then recursively call the callbacks once all promises are complete the order can be corrected.

```js
let order = 0
const promiseTree = (name, children) => 
  Promise.all([
    // --------------------- resolve a closure with the resolved value contained
    new Promise(res => res(() => `${name} order:${order++}`)),
    children && Promise.all(children)
  ])

// flatMap over the tree, if it's a function call it and return the result
const recursivelyCall = x => 
  Array.isArray(x)
    ? x.map(recursivelyCall)
    : typeof(x) === 'function' ? x() : x

promiseTree('root', [
  promiseTree('child', [
    promiseTree('grandchild', [
      promiseTree('great grandchild sibling 1'),
      promiseTree('great grandchild sibling 2'),
    ])
  ])
])
// traverse the returned values and call the functions in declared order
.then(recursivelyCall)
.then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js?concise=true"></script>
```

Cheers

Comment: In your first example your not showing the execution order, but the resolved order.  IOW:  Do a console.log as well as resolving the value you will see it better.

Comment: @Keith Sorry I have misspoken. I only care about the resolved order of the promises. They are used in an asynchronous node tree, eg the parent node may download a html template from the server, and the child node may add functionality to the html template, so the parent must be executed before the child. The first example shows that the child is executed first.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck with this question because "return a closure" and "resolve a closure" don't ring true. Closures are not things that can be either returned or resolved.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks for pointing out the discrepancy. I have corrected it to resolve as you can't return a value from a promise. closure is just a way to say function. it can be resolved from a Promise, then called from the `then` function. eg. `Promise.resolve(() => 'resolved value').then(fn => console.log(fn()))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the pattern at the code at the first snippet is that the inner-most nested function (argument) is executed first; see and highlight line `15` at https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/777805a289e129cd29706b54268cfcfc/5a2def5def7d8ee91c052d9733bc7a37c63a6f67, https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1397.

> I would prefer to not use async/await and just stick with `Promise`'s
>   or another Functional JS object.

It is not clear why that option is excluded from consideration. An `async` function is an instance of `Promise`. Given the requirement `async/await` is a viable solution.

```js
console.log((async() => void 0)() instanceof Promise);

const fn = async() => {
  let order = 0
  const promiseTree = name =>
    new Promise(res => res(`${name} order:${order++}`))

  const res = [await promiseTree('root'), [
    await promiseTree('child'), [
      await promiseTree('grandchild'), [
        await promiseTree('great grandchild sibling 1')
      , await promiseTree('great grandchild sibling 2')
      ]
    ]
  ]];
  return res;
}

fn()
.then(console.log)
```

Comment: The reason for not wanting to use *await* is that it would increase the complexity of the usage. I have created a Node tree with different types to build the functionality for a site by piecing together different nodes, eg, one is a predicate that can be used for routing or conditional functionality for a page, one is a housing for a module, one is a plugin type that interacts with the DOM. I am abstracting the promises away from the end user so the public api is just `new Module([ new Module([ new Plugin() ]), new Plugin() ])` They just create a tree structure with the functionality they need

Comment: Here is a link to my question on Code review. It's much more indepth about the problem and the reasons for my choices with an example of the api. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211018/execute-promise-tree-in-order-of-declaration

Comment: @synthet1c `async/await` reduces complexity of the code from perspective here. As pointed out in the code at Code Review answer the nested array structure can be created in a functional manner. The pattern used at the code at either question has the issue of the innermost function being executed first.